# How to pass the second variable to the Vue Laravel component and set it by default to the input variable?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am starting to learn Vue. Please tell me what my code should look like when I need to pass 2 value to my component?

```html
<div id="js-autocomplete-region">
  <autocomplete-region-component :query-prop="{{ json_encode(old('regionName', $advert->region->name)) }}"></autocomplete-region-component>
</div>
```

in addition to $advert->region->name, I need to pass another $advert->region->id

this my code component vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"                
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="query"
            v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
            class="form-control js-region-name"
            name="regionName"
            value=""
        >
        <input
            type="hidden"
            class="form-control js-region-id"
            name="regionId"
            value="">
        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
            <ul class="list-group select-region">
                <li class="list-group-item list-region" v-for="result in results" v-on:click="selectRegion(result)">
                    {{ result.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            queryProp: {
                required: false,
                type: String
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                results: [],
                query: this.queryProp
            };
        },
        methods: {
            autoComplete() {
                this.results = [];
                if(this.query.length > 2){
                    axios.get('/api/regions',{params: {_limit: 2, query: this.query}}).then(response => {
                        this.results = response.data;
                    });
                }
            },
            selectRegion(result) {
                let inputWithRegionName = document.querySelector('.js-region-name');
                let inputWithRegionId = document.querySelector('.js-region-id');
                let listRegions = document.querySelector('.panel-footer');

                inputWithRegionName.value = result.name;
                inputWithRegionId.value = result.id;
                listRegions.hidden = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

if there is $advert->region->id then it should be set here

[image]

---

### update

```html
<autocomplete-region-component
      :query-prop="{{ json_encode(old('regionName', $advert->region->name)) }}"
      other-value="{{ $advert->region ? $advert->region->id : '' }}"
      @other-input="{{ $advert->region ? $advert->region->id : '' }}"
></autocomplete-region-component>
```

updating for component and screenshot

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Начните вводить ваш город и выберите его из списка"
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="query"
            v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
            class="form-control js-region-name"
            name="regionName"
            value=""
        >
        <input
            type="hidden"
            class="form-control js-region-id"
            name="regionId"
            value="">
        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
            <ul class="list-group select-region">
                <li class="list-group-item list-region" v-for="result in results" v-on:click="selectRegion(result)">
                    {{ result.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            queryProp: {
                required: false,
                type: String
            }
        },
        computed: {
            val2: {
                get() {
                    return this.otherValue;
                },
                set(newValue) {
                    this.$emit('other-input', newValue);
                },
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                results: [],
                query: this.queryProp
            };
        },
        methods: {
            autoComplete() {
                this.results = [];
                if(this.query.length > 2){
                    axios.get('/api/regions',{params: {_limit: 2, query: this.query}}).then(response => {
                        this.results = response.data;
                    });
                }
            },
            selectRegion(result) {
                let inputWithRegionName = document.querySelector('.js-region-name');
                let inputWithRegionId = document.querySelector('.js-region-id');
                let listRegions = document.querySelector('.panel-footer');

                inputWithRegionName.value = result.name;
                inputWithRegionId.value = result.id;
                listRegions.hidden = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Vlad, I have updated my answer with a working example. I think all that was missing in your code was to bind the value by using ":value="property".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad, nearly there, you pass the second prop just as you did with the first one. You should then bind (v-model) the input to this value, however doing jus that will cause an error (avoid mutating a prop),So use as prop, maybe, initRegion, the data variable you maybe call region and set it to this.initRegion. If you struggle, let me know.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue Testing</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">

        <autocomplete-region-component
            query-prop="regionName"
            init-region="1"
        >
        </autocomplete-region-component>

    </div>
    <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>

        Vue.component('autocomplete-region-component', {
      props: {
          queryProp: {
              required: false,
              type: String
          },
          initRegion: {
              required: false,
              type: String
          }
      },
      computed: {
          val2: {
              get() {
                  return this.otherValue;
              },
              set(newValue) {
                  this.$emit('other-input', newValue);
              },
          },
      },
      data() {
          return {
              results: [],
              query: this.queryProp,
              region: this.initRegion
          };
      },
      methods: {
          autoComplete() {
              this.results = [];
              if(this.query.length > 2){
                  axios.get('/api/regions',{params: {_limit: 2, query: this.query}}).then(response => {
                      this.results = response.data;
                  });
              }
          },
          selectRegion(result) {
              let inputWithRegionName = document.querySelector('.js-region-name');
              let inputWithRegionId = document.querySelector('.js-region-id');
              let listRegions = document.querySelector('.panel-footer');

              inputWithRegionName.value = result.name;
              inputWithRegionId.value = result.id;
              listRegions.hidden = true;
          }
      },
            template:`
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Начните вводить ваш город и выберите его из списка"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    v-model="query"
                    v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
                    class="form-control js-region-name"
                    name="regionName"
                    value=""
                >
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    class="form-control js-region-id"
                    name="regionId"
                    :value="region">
                <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
                    <ul class="list-group select-region">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-region" v-for="result in results" v-on:click="selectRegion(result)">
                            {{ result.name }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            `,
            mounted() {
                //
            }
        })

        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {},
        })  

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As the input is hidden, I pressume you don't care to change the id further. In that case actually you don't even have to use it as a data property.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many values as you want via props, however there is only one "value" that will interact with v-model.

The good news is that v-model is really just a handy abstracted pattern for components.

You could make a second "value" in a component as follows:

```
<!-- updateV2 method sets v2 to value raised in the event -->

<my-component
    v-model="v1"
    other-value="v2"
    @other-input="updateV2"
></my-component>
```

```
computed: {
    val2() {
        get() {
            return this.otherValue;
        },
        set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('other-input', newValue);
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: updated main post, I tried to do as they wrote, but I still have no region in the variable in the variable. Please help with an example on my code if this does not bother you. I will be very grateful

Comment: Vlad, did you sort it out in the meantime?